# How do autosaves work in Kingdoms of Amalur?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

What is the autosave policy in KoA? Is there a difference between the consoles and the PC?

Answer (score 2):

On the console (Xbox 360 in my case) it autosaves every time I zone change, including going in and out of houses. The PC version may be a bit more liberal with autosaves, but I can't see is as by much more than that.

Comment: It can also auto-save before or after large events, such as boss battles. For example, the quest where you choose what Fae to kill for their armor will autosave directly afterwards so you can't load and kill the other guy.

Comment: I can confirm that the PS3 will also autosave after zone changes (fast travel, entering buildings and dungeons) and significant events (boss fights, quest completion (full or in part), trophy achievements and leveling).